# Prestashop get Category Uri

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have problem with getting category Uri in prestashop 1.7 .

```
Context::getContext()->link->getCategoryLink($categoryId)
```

its return "http://mydomain/pl/1-baza" i need only "pl/1-baza" or "1-baza"

```
return Category::getLinkRewrite($categoryId],$languageId)
```

its return only "baza"

And

```
 $cat=new Category($categoryId,$languageId);
return $cat->getLink()
```

return "http://mydomain/pl/1-baza"

i try to retrive all categories uri in my custom module.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the rewritten link from the $**cat** object.

In your case :

```
$cat = new Category($categoryId,$languageId);
$myCatUri = $cat->id.'-'.$cat->link_rewrite;
```

will produce: **1-baza**

Comment: But it won't  work when someone change in seo {{rewrite}-{id}. It can't be static. :(

Comment: Then you can use $link->getBaseLink to get the base URI once in your script, so you can remove it from $cat->getLink() result afterwards.  Or you can build your own function ... It's pretty straightforward. Check getCategoryLink() method in Link.php core file.

Comment: I have to Use Dispatcher createUrl method,but im so disappoint prestashop's Api.Its hell for developers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, it worked.

```
Context::getContext()->link->getCategoryLink(`CATEGORY ID`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Create a link to a category.
 *
 * @param Category|array|int $category Category object (can be an ID category, but deprecated)
 * @param string|null $alias
 * @param int|null $idLang
 * @param string|null $selectedFilters Url parameter to autocheck filters of the module blocklayered
 * @param int|null $idShop
 * @param bool $relativeProtocol
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCategoryLink(
    $category,
    $alias = null,
    $idLang = null,
    $selectedFilters = null,
    $idShop = null,
    $relativeProtocol = false
)
```